# ActiveRecord. Create joint table link. Shortest way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm trying to get an oneliner when adding a role to a user. I'm using many to many relationship, and my joint table is called UserRoles.

What is the shortest way of doing that?

My best solution was:

`user.user_roles << UserRole.create(role_id: 1)`

The issue I have with it is, that I have to rely on `role_id`. I want to find it by the string, so it is clear in the code what role it is.

Answer (score 0):

`user.user_roles.create(role_id: 1)` would be a more concise way to create the role.

If you want to use role strings you can use constants in your model that you can reference. But then you should add a `role` attribute to your model.

```
class UserRoles
  ROLES = ['A', 'B']

  validates_inclusion_of :role, in: ROLES
end
```

`validates_inclusion_of` will validate that you have an allowed role before creating the object.

Comment: Thanks, that helped finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with it and decided to go with the following:

`user.user_roles << Role.find_by(role: 'registered').user_roles.create`